# java nio path can't handle windows network path

Tags: java, nio

Why does this happen?

```
def path=java.nio.file.Paths.get("c:/kittuhomestore/Csmart/files/companies");
path.getNameCount();
4

def path=java.nio.file.Paths.get("//kittuhomestore/Csmart/files/companies");
path.getNameCount();
2
```

The latter is a windows shared network drive.

Comment: It seems like `/kittuhomestore/Csmart` is the network path, `/files` is a directory on the root, and `/companies` is a directory inside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get("c:/kittuhomestore/Csmart/files/companies");
System.err.println(path.getRoot());
```

Output:

```
c:\
```

In the first case, the `Root` of the path is `C:\`, so the remaining parts are `kittuhomestore`, `Csmart`, `files` and `companies`, hence **4** components.

---

```
Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get("//kittuhomestore/Csmart/files/companies");
System.err.println(path.getRoot());
```

Output:

```
\\kittuhomestore\Csmart\
```

In the second case, the `Root` of the path is `\\kittuhomestore\Csmart\`, so the remaining parts are `files` and `companies`, hence **2** components.

This is because an [UNC path](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm) has the format

```
\\server\share\file_path
```

where `\\server\share` is the root of the path.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you set such a path up on your own system? Was it simple?

Comment: No, its not necessary - only creating a `Path` object does not yet access the file system

Comment: Honestly, I also forgot it first, and used an existing path for my initial check :D